# OpenSearch Java Client: bulk update for existing document results in 400 bad request

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am implementing a [bulk update](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/document-apis/bulk/) operation using an [OpenSearch Java client](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/java/) for existing documents stored in the OpenSearch provisioned by AWS.

The `BulkRequest` request object looks like this:

```
BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest.Builder().operations(o -> o.update(u -> u.index(indexName).id(String.valueOf(id)).document(doc))).build();
        
openSearchClient.bulk(request);
```

The `doc` object is a POJO object that reflects a document inside the index.

```
public class ProgramSelectionInfoBase implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6880667215923483985L;

    private long id;
    private String status35;
    // other fields, getters, setters.

}
```

The response I am getting is **400 Bad Request**

In the debug mode, the parsed bulk request looks different as it should per the [bulk update](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/document-apis/bulk/) documentation. It lacks the `"doc"` parent object, which should wrap the partially updated document:

```
{ "update" : { "_id" : "361710", "_index" : "program_search" }}
{ "status35": "draft" }. <- doc is missing.


{ "update": { "_index": "movies", "_id": "tt0816711" } }
{ "doc": { "title": "World War Z" } }
```

If I replace a bulk update request with a single [document update](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/document-apis/update-document/#example) request, I get successful results. The parsed request structure matches the documentation one:

```
UpdateRequest<Object, Object> request = new UpdateRequest.Builder<>().id(String.valueOf(id)).doc(doc).index(indexName).build();
openSearchClient.update(request, Object.class);

{"doc":{"status35":"active"}}
```

**Question:** Am I building a `BulkRequest` object incorrectly? Or this is the client library issue?

**UPDATE** I am using the latest available OpenSearch Java client [version](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/java/#installing-the-client-using-restclient-transport)

Comment: Looks like someone or the questioner has opened a bug issue ticket. Leaving it here to be traced -> https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-java/issues/590

Comment: could you please try the following code and report if the error is the same? `UpdateOperation<Object> updateOperation = new UpdateOperation.Builder<>().document(doc).index(indexName).id(id).build();
        BulkOperation bulkOperation = new BulkOperation.Builder().update(updateOperation).build();
        request.operations().add(bulkOperation);`

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos, thanks for the suggestion. I will try and let you know.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos, I tried your suggestion above and it didn't work I am still getting 400 responses. The parsed JSON looks incorrect. ```{ "update" : { "_id" : "361710", "_index" : "program_search" }}
{ "status35": "closed" }.```

Answer (score 0):

I come up with the two workarounds while waiting for the response:

1.The current requirements allow me to switch to a single document update option. As mentioned in the question it works successfully. However, there is a high probability that in future I would need to update a set of documents, which is better to do using the bulk option.

2.Create a class wrapper. It will have a `doc` field which allows receiving a required request structure after converting the object to JSON:

```
public class UpdateRootDocument<T> {

    T doc;

    public UpdateRootDocument(T doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    public T getDoc() {
        return doc;
    }

    public void setDoc(T doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are making a good progress